# Prolog Finding Kth element in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying write a predicate in prolog to find Kth element in a list.
Example:

```
?- element_at(X,[a,b,c,d,e],3).
X = c
```

my code as follows

```
k_ele(X,[X|_],1).
k_ele(X,[_|T],Y) :- Y > 1,Y is Y - 1, k_ele(X,T,Y).
```

But no use, I found solution on Internet as

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1).
element_at(X,[_|L],K) :- K > 1, K1 is K - 1, element_at(X,L,K1).
```

Which is same as my logic except they used one extra variable K1.

What is wrong with my code, why I need another variable ?

Comment: In prolog, variables aren't "assigned" as they are in many other languages you're more familiar with. Variables are "unified" (as @dasblinkenlight says in his answer) - which means Prolog seeks to find values for the variables that make the statement they are in true. No value of `Y` makes `Y is Y - 1` true, so it will always fail. `K1 is K - 1` will unify `K1` to the value of `K -1` if `K` is already defined. Once a variable is unified, it cannot be changed in a clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is that unification is not an assignment. When you say

```
Y is Y - 1
```

you are trying to unify a value of `Y` with the value of `Y-1`, which is mathematically impossible. This is roughly the same as saying `4 is 3` or `1001 is 1000`. The entire condition fails, leading to the failure to find the element in the list.

The fixed solution that you have found on the internet introduces a separate variable `K1`, which is unified with `K - 1`. This is very much doable: `K1` gets the value to which `K-1` evaluates, the condition succeeds, and the clause moves on to the recursive invocation part.

Answer (score 2):

Because variables in prolog are write-once critters. Having been [assigned|unified with|bound to] a non-variable value, it ceases to be variable. It is henceforth that value. Unlike more...conventional...programming languages, once bound, the only way to reassign a prolog variable is to backtrack through the assignment and undo it.

It should be noted, though, that a variable can be unified with another variable: Given a predicate something like

```
foo(X,Y) :- X = Y .
```

and something like

```
shazam(X,Y) :- bar(X,Y) , X = 3.
```

will result in both X and Y being 3. Having been unified, X and Y are both the same variable, albeit with different names.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're working with the exercises from this link:

http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/problemas-prolog/

Note, in my opinion the original solution is not the best either.

For example, a query:

```
element_at(X,[a,b,c],Y).
```

would crash, even if there are 3 solutions:

- X = a, Y = 1;
- X = b, Y = 2;
- X = c, Y = 3;

I believe writing in an alternative way:

```
element_at(H, [H | _], 1).
element_at(H, [_ | T], N) :- element_at(H, T, NMinus1), N is NMinus1 + 1.
```

would give better results. It's less efficient as one can not apply the last call optimization, but the logic becomes more general.

Comment: s(X) for your answer. Efficient? No. Inspiring? Most definitely. Thanks!